# pycharm don't see things installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

From the start of using pycharm i am facing problems with working with libraries

I tried reinstalling python, pip, pycharm; adding and readding to path. I also tried using pipenv instead of virtenv.. and it worked once, but.. now again-
i use $pip install numpy |as example| in cmd window it says to be successfully installed. Go to pycharm, type 'import numpy'.. and nothing happens. I know i can download manually: go to settings and so on.. but it would be much beter if pip installed with cmd would be instantly displayed in Pycharm. Anybody, please, help.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip --version` and also this code in pycharm `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have activated the virtual environment in which you have installed the packages. For instance you may have installed the package on Global python version and running your program on a virtual environment which will not work. So maybe try activating your virtual environment before installing the Packages.

## Step 1:-

> `activate {name_of_pipenv}`

> `pip install numpy`